# Firebase hosting serve gzip file instead of content

Tags: firebase, url-rewriting, deep-linking, firebase-hosting

We are using firebase solutions to host a website.

We are having an issue with static file in firebase hosting. We are trying to serve apple-app-site-association as a "regular file" (content type : text plain or json) but, when I enter mysite.com/apple-app-site-association in a browser => my browser download a file gzipped.
In http://localhost:5000/apple-app-site-association, it is working properly. Is firebase.json rewrite rule working in local mode ?

What can we do?

For example on this website http://fr.vestiairecollective.com/apple-app-site-association, the apple-app-site-association is readable directly in browser.

A the end, it seems that apple devices does not understand the file and then deeplinking is not working.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Hosting allows you to overwrite headers, including `Content-Type`, so you could try setting a rule like the following:

```js
{
  "hosting": {
    "headers": [{
      "source": "apple-app-site-association",
      "headers": [{
        "key": "Content-Type",
        "value": "application/json"
      }]
    }]
  }
}
```

(or `application/pkcs7-mime` if you'd like to serve it encrypted for iOS 8.x)